# ¿Como añadir TIPOS a un diccionario como claves o valores en C#?

Tags: c#, diccionarios, conversión-de-tipos

Me gustaría añadir elementos a un diccionario, donde el Key sería un string y el value sería un tipo de dato (nombres de clases).

La idea es algo así:

```
Dictionary<string, System.Type> hiter = new Dictionary<string, System.Type>();
hiter.Add("Tag1", ClassName1);
hiter.Add("Tag2", ClassName2);
```

He probado con "System.Type" pero el compilador me da el siguiente error:

**Error CS0119  'ClassName1' es tipo, que no es válida en el contexto indicado**

¿Alguna forma de poder hacer esto?
Gracias!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, está resuelo... se hace asi:

```
hiter.Add("tag", typeof(ClassName1));
```

Fuente:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2948034